# get the title on live video in youtube using API YouTube V3

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

i am using API Live Streaming youtube to retrieve list of live chat messages on youtube video using id_video, exits serveral properties that appear in this resource such as snippet.liveChatId, snippet.displayMessage which i can found them from this ressource, 
so my question is how can i get the title on live video in channel youtube which is not for me  ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list). The [`items[]`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list#properties) property will return a list of live streams that match the request criteria.

```
{
  ...
  },
  "items": [
    liveStream Resource
  ]
}
```

The following JSON structure shows the format of a [`liveStreams` resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#resource):

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#liveStream",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "isDefaultStream": boolean
  },
  ...
}
```